# Search form using ajax, php and json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

i'm currently learning javascript through my school and I'm completely stuck on trying to make a search form work.

The problem I have is that I can't get it to show all results from the sql query.

The code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var searchfield = document.getElementById("searchfield");
  var searchresult = document.getElementById("searchresult");
 $(searchfield).on("keyup", function(){
  var q = this.value;
  console.log(q +"'This value'");
  var str = "";
  var url = "searchscript.php?q="+q;
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resultat){
      console.log("resultatet är:" + resultat.ProduktNamn);
     for(var i = 0; i < resultat.ProduktNamn.length; i++) {
      str += resultat.ProduktNamn + "<br>";
     }

      searchresult.innerHTML = str;
   }
  })
 });
});
```

```html
<?php
$str = $_GET['q'];
if (!empty($str)) {
 $query = "SELECT ProduktNamn FROM Produkter WHERE ProduktNamn LIKE '%$str%'";
 $resultat = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
  while ($row = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row);
  }

}

?>
```

As soon as the result of the query has more than 1 property, no matter how I do it it won't show any results, only when I narrow down the search so that only one product is found it shows it.

I'm new to javascript, but I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that the way I'm doing it on the PHP side makes it so it returns every product as a single object, not within an array or anything, so when I get the data back on the javascript side I have trouble looping through it.

So basically, say I have these products

"Banana Chiquita"
"Banana Chichi"
"Banana"

I will only get a result on the javascript side once I've written atleast "Banana chiq" in the search field so the php side only returns 1 object.

Sorry for my terrible explaination :/

Comment: Another example: 

I go to searchscript.php?q=ba 

And it returns:
{"ProduktNamn":"Banan Chiquita"}{"ProduktNamn":"Banan Lokal"}

which is all products which has "ba" in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you should make a 2D array and then encode it to JSON. Currently, you are writing out each record as a JSON string which will work for a single record but not for multiple records. See the corrected PHP code.

```
<?php
$str = $_GET['q'];
if (!empty($str)) {
   $query = "SELECT ProduktNamn FROM Produkter WHERE ProduktNamn LIKE '%$str%'";
   $resultat = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
   $rows = array();
   while ($row = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
      array_push($rows,$row);

   }
   echo json_encode($rows);

}

?>
```